# How to sort an array from a specific key?

Tags: swift, dictionary, nested, sorteddictionary

Currently, I have an array declared as :

```
let VitamineARetinol = "VitamineARetinol"
let VitamineABetacarotene = "VitamineABetacarotene"
let VitamineC = "VitamineC"
let VitamineD = "VitamineD"
let Calories = "Calories"

typealias ListOfAliment = [String: [String: Double]]


let Data: ListOfAliment = [
    "Orange": [VitamineARetinol: 0.5, VitamineC: 0.3, VitamineD: 0.98, Calories: 100],
    "Pomme": [VitamineARetinol: 0.2, VitamineC: 0.2, VitamineD: 0.38, Calories: 120],
    "Poire": [VitamineARetinol: 0.1, VitamineC: 0.7, VitamineD: 0.58, Calories: 140],
    "Laitue": [VitamineARetinol: 0.3, VitamineC: 0.1, VitamineD: 0.92, Calories: 105],
    "Banane": [VitamineARetinol: 0.7, VitamineC: 0.01, VitamineD: 0.63, Calories: 122]
]

var ListOfAlimentClassed = Data
```

I need to sort it from the Calories key, while keeping all the array data, like this:

```
ListOfAlimentClassed = [
"Orange": [VitamineARetinol: 0.5, VitamineC: 0.3, VitamineD: 0.98, Calories: 100],
"Laitue": [VitamineARetinol: 0.3, VitamineC: 0.1, VitamineD: 0.92, Calories: 105],
"Pomme": [VitamineARetinol: 0.2, VitamineC: 0.2, VitamineD: 0.38, Calories: 120],
"Banane": [VitamineARetinol: 0.7, VitamineC: 0.01, VitamineD: 0.63, Calories: 122],
"Poire": [VitamineARetinol: 0.1, VitamineC: 0.7, VitamineD: 0.58, Calories: 140]
]
```

How could I efficiently do this in Swift? Please help!

Comment: You cannot sort a Dictionary, they are by definition, an unsorted collection.

Comment: You don't sort a dictionary, it's key/value system, not index/value system. You kind of can do it, but you'll lose the fact that it's a dictionary afterwards (since you can get tuples where key/values), but that won't be a dictionary afterwards.

Comment: ok, so how could i sort this data from the less caloriques to the most one, even if i have to change the type of dictionary to another?

Comment: Create a struct for your data instead and use an array instead with instances of the struct

Comment: Please could you show me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a struct for your data and use an array for it instead

```
struct Aliment {
    let name: String
    let vitamineARetinol: Double
    let vitaminC: Double
    let vitaminD: Double
    let calories: Double
}

var array = [
    Aliment(name: "Orange", vitamineARetinol: 0.5, vitaminC: 0.3, vitaminD: 0.98, calories: 100),
    Aliment(name: "Pomme", vitamineARetinol: 0.2, vitaminC: 0.2, vitaminD: 0.38, calories: 120),
]

array.sort(by: { $0.calories < $1.calories })
```

Read more about structures in the [Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html) book

Comment: Thank you a lot, i am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

```
let sorted = ListOfAlimentClassed.sorted { (($0.1[Calories] as? Double) ?? 0) < (($1.1[Calories] as? Double) ?? 0) }
```

Comment: This solution is good only if the aliments like orange, pomme, ... haven't the same name. othewise the program crashs!