# Multiply one dictionary by another in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, nested

Currently, I have a nested dictionary declared as :

```
let VitamineARetinol = "VitamineARetinol"
let VitamineABetacarotene = "VitamineABetacarotene"
let VitamineC = "VitamineC"
let VitamineD = "VitamineD"
let Calories = "Calories"

typealias ListOfAliment = [String: [String: Double]]

let Data: ListOfAliment = [
    "Orange": [VitamineARetinol: 0.5, VitamineC: 0.3, VitamineD: 0.98, Calories: 160],
    "Pomme": [VitamineARetinol: 0.2, VitamineC: 0.2, VitamineD: 0.38, Calories: 120],
    "Poire": [VitamineARetinol: 0.1, VitamineC: 0.7, VitamineD: 0.58, Calories: 140],
    "Laitue": [VitamineARetinol: 0.3, VitamineC: 0.1, VitamineD: 0.92, Calories: 105],
    "Banane": [VitamineARetinol: 0.7, VitamineC: 0.01, VitamineD: 0.63, Calories: 122],
]
```

And I need to divide each value with its corresponding value in the following dictionary:

```
let reference: ListOfAliment = [
    "reference": [VitamineARetinol: 0.2, VitamineC: 0.1, VitamineD: 0.4],
]
```

In the end, I should get a food dictionary where all the values ​​of each food have been divided by their corresponding value in the dictionary reference
Please, could someone help me!

Comment: Any reason why you are not using your own struct?

Comment: Could you show me how to create the good one, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given my answer in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63355058/9223839) you can simply map your array of values into a new array

```
let adjustedData = array
    .map { Aliment(name: $0.name, 
                   vitamineARetinol: $0.vitamineARetinol / 0.2, 
                   vitaminC: $0.vitaminC / 0.1, 
                   vitaminD: $0.vitaminD / 0.4, 
                   calories: $0.calories)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely create a structs for the inner dictionary. Because then you can add a `dividedBy` method in the struct to do the division. I'm not sure if it makes sense to "divide" one aliment by another aliment. If it does, you can change the `divideBy` method to accept another `Aliment` instead.

```
struct Aliment {
    let vitaminARetinol: Double
    let vitaminC: Double
    let vitaminD: Double
    let calories: Double
    
    func dividedBy(vitaminARetinolFactor: Double, vitaminCFactor: Double, vitaminDFactor: Double, caloriesFactor: Double) -> Aliment {
        Aliment(vitaminARetinol: vitaminARetinol / vitaminARetinolFactor,
                vitaminC: vitaminC / vitaminCFactor,
                vitaminD: vitaminD / vitaminDFactor,
                calories: calories / caloriesFactor)
    }
}
typealias ListOfAliment = [String: Aliment]
let data: ListOfAliment = [
    "Orange": Aliment(vitaminARetinol: 0.5, vitaminC: 0.3, vitaminD: 0.98, calories: 160),
    "Pomme": Aliment(vitaminARetinol: 0.2, vitaminC: 0.2, vitaminD: 0.38, calories: 120),
    "Poire": Aliment(vitaminARetinol: 0.1, vitaminC: 0.7, vitaminD: 0.58, calories: 140),
    "Laitue": Aliment(vitaminARetinol: 0.3, vitaminC: 0.1, vitaminD: 0.92, calories: 105),
    "Banane": Aliment(vitaminARetinol: 0.7, vitaminC: 0.01, vitaminD: 0.63, calories: 122),
]
```

To transform the dictionary, you can use `mapValues`:

```
let referenceNumbers = reference["reference"]!
let newData = data.mapValues { 
    $0.dividedBy(vitaminARetinolFactor: referenceNumbers[VitamineARetinol]!, 
                 vitaminCFactor: referenceNumbers[VitamineC]!, 
                 vitaminDFactor: referenceNumbers[VitamineD]!, 
                 caloriesFactor: referenceNumbers[Calories]!) 
}
```

Again, if it makes sense to divide one aliment by another, you can make the reference an `Aliment` object too, and pass it to `divideBy`.